# How can we change time format in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

In django Template i am getting time in this format like :

17 : 19 : 05

I want to convert this in : 5:19 Pm format

how can i convert this in this format can anyone please help me related this ??

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date & display as your wish by following django documentation.
It should be `%g %i %A`. Refer [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date) for more information.

Comment: i am saving time in db in this format only and i want when i want to display it should be in form of like : 5:19 Pm